# Plotly: how to add data labels to a Choropleth

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following `Pandas` dataframe `df` that looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'state' : ['NY', 'CA', 'FL', 'NJ', 'TX', 'CT', 'MA', 'WA', 'IL', 'GA'],
                   'user_id' : [10000, 3200, 1600, 1200, 800, 600, 400, 350, 270, 260]
                        })

    state   user_id
0   NY      10000
1   CA      3200
2   FL      1600
3   NJ      1200
4   TX      800
5   CT      600
6   MA      400
7   WA      350
8   IL      270
9   GA      260
```

I'd like to be able to create a Plotly choropleth that includes **data labels** over each of the states.

To do so, I use `add_scattergeo`:

```
fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    locations = 'state', 
                    locationmode = "USA-states", 
                    scope = "usa",
                    color = 'user_id',
                    color_continuous_scale = "blues",
                    )
fig.add_scattergeo(
                   locations = df['state'],
                   text = df['user_id'],
                   mode = 'text',
                   )

fig.show()
```

[image]

But, using `add_scattergeo` does not apply the desired labels.

What's the best way to add data labels to a Plotly choropleth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also add `locationmode="USA-states"` to `add_scattergeo`:

```
fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations='state', 
    locationmode="USA-states", 
    scope="usa",                    
    color='user_id',
    color_continuous_scale="blues",
)
fig.add_scattergeo(
    locations=df['state'],
    locationmode="USA-states", 
    text=df['user_id'],
    mode='text',
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In the case where the labels are close together (e.g. Maryland and Washington DC), is there a way to prevent the labels from overlapping?  (note:  those don't appear in the code I posted, but are likely to occur if we extend this example)

Comment: Hmm, not sure.  There is some discussion of overlapping labels here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168846/how-to-avoid-overlapping-text-in-a-plotly-scatter-plot